# Why can't I delete groups in Sharepoint Foundation 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a test group I created in SharePoint that I want to delete (I'm the only user in the group). In the "People and Groups: All Groups" screen I click the edit icon next to the group and then click on the "Delete" button and ok the following warning dialog. However, the group doesn't get deleted. Any idea why this is happening and how to finally delete this group? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Site Actions -> Site Settings -> People and Groups
2. Click on the group and check all the users -> Actions -> Remove Users from Group
3. Click on Settings -> Group Settings -> then click delete at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's because of [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/58259240-8e18-4142-8e37-c9f42009c12d):

> When you install a new farm with your own credentials, you are
>   automatically Site Collection administrator of the Central
>   administration application.
>
> Because I had installed my farm (with Powershell) with another
>   ‘installation’ account, then that ‘installation’ account was Site
>   Collection administrator.
>
> After I put my own account to the Site Collection administrator group,
>   I could remove the SharePoint group without any problems.
>
> I was a little confused because when I want to delete that SharePoint
>   group without the necessary permissions, you don’t get any warning or
>   error message.

In a nutshell, being a site collection administrator is the minimum permissions level necessary.